# Why isn't SDL displaying my texture?

Tags: sdl2

I am self teaching SDL game programming from SDL Game Development Black and White textbook.

I stopped at the second chapter, where I have to display .bmp picture on screen.

Given code:

```
SDL_Surface* pTempSurface = SDL_LoadBMP("assets/rider.bmp");

m_pTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(m_pRenderer,pTempSurface);
SDL_FreeSurface(pTempSurface);

SDL_QueryTexture(m_pTexture, NULL, NULL, &m_sourceRectangle.w, &m_sourceRectangle.h);
m_destinationRectangle.x = m_sourceRectangle.x = 0;
m_destinationRectangle.y = m_sourceRectangle.y = 0;
m_destinationRectangle.w = m_sourceRectangle.w;
m_destinationRectangle.h = m_sourceRectangle.h;
```

should be loaded inside init function of Game1.cpp, as author tells

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game1.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

Game::Game()
{

}

bool Game::init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, int flags)
{
    SDL_Surface* pTempSurface = SDL_LoadBMP("assets/rider.bmp");

    m_pTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(m_pRenderer, pTempSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(pTempSurface);

    SDL_QueryTexture(m_pTexture, NULL, NULL, &m_sourceRectangle.w, &m_sourceRectangle.h);
    m_destinationRectangle.x = m_sourceRectangle.x = 0;
    m_destinationRectangle.y = m_sourceRectangle.y = 0;
    m_destinationRectangle.w = m_sourceRectangle.w;
    m_destinationRectangle.h = m_sourceRectangle.h;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL init success\n";
        m_pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);  

        if(m_pWindow != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "window creation success\n";
            m_pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_pWindow, -1, 0); 

            if(m_pRenderer != 0)
            {
                std::cout << "renderer creation success\n";
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_pRenderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "renderer init fail\n";
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "window init fail\n";
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "SDL init fail\n";
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "init success\n";
    m_bRunning = true;

    return true;
}

void Game::render()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(m_pRenderer);

    SDL_RenderCopy(m_pRenderer, m_pTexture, &m_sourceRectangle, &m_destinationRectangle);

    SDL_RenderPresent(m_pRenderer);
}

void Game::SDL_Quit()
{
    std::cout << "cleaning game\n";
    SDL_DestroyWindow(m_pWindow);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_pRenderer);
}

void Game::clean()
{
    std::cout << "cleaning game\n";
    SDL_DestroyWindow(m_pWindow);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_pRenderer);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Game1.h

```
#ifndef GAME1_H
#define GAME1_H
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class Game

{
public:

    Game();
    ~Game();

    bool init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, int flags);

    void render();
    void update();
    void handleEvents();
    void clean();
    void SDL_Quit();

    bool running() { return m_bRunning; }

private:

    SDL_Window* m_pWindow;
    SDL_Renderer* m_pRenderer;

    SDL_Texture* m_pTexture; // the new SDL_Texture variable
    SDL_Rect m_sourceRectangle; // the first rectangle
    SDL_Rect m_destinationRectangle; // another rectangle

    bool m_bRunning;
};



#endif // GAME1_H_INCLUDED
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Game1.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>


Game* g_game = 0;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{

    g_game = new Game();

    g_game->init("Chapter 1", 100, 100, 640, 480, 0);

    while(g_game->running())
    {
        g_game->handleEvents();
        g_game->update();
        g_game->render();
    }
    g_game->clean();

    return 0;
}

void Game::handleEvents()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                m_bRunning = false;
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When build this in CodeBlocks I get no error. Even window loads, but there is no rider.bmp image on window screen.

What is wrong? Should given code be placed somewhere else inside init()?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize SDL before calling `SDL_LoadBMP` and construct the renderer before calling `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`. It's a good rule of thumb to initialize SDL and create the window and renderer before doing anything else.

So simply move that code to bottom of `init`.

Comment: Supposed that problem is in position of author code. But, even with moving code to bottom of init I still get empty screen again.

Comment: Are you checking `SDL_GetError`?

Comment: Finally, it works. Completely forgot to check SDL_GetError. Error was in wrong path for rider.bmp picture. Thank you!